# Compare a null list with [(a,b)] Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, boolean, tuples

I am a bit confused on how the lists in Haskell works.
I know that `[]` is an empty list with type [a].Is there a way to define an empty list with type [(a,b)]?

For example I know that `null [1] == []` will give us `True`

`null [(1,2)] == []` gave me the mismatched type error that's what I am assuming.

I want to know if it is possible to say something like `null [(1,2)] == [(,)]` will give us `True`

Comment: `null [1] == []` is a type error.

Comment: yes, `let { xs = tail [(undefined,undefined)] } in null xs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know that `[]` is an empty list with type `[a]`

Yes, but it's important to understand what “type `[a]`” actually means. Really it means type `forall a . [a]`, i.e. this is not a list of elements of some particular type “a” but rather, *given any choice of type `a`*, it is a list of that type. In particular, it can also be a list of tuple type. Thus, `null` works just as fine with lists of tuples as with lists of any other type.

To actually see `null` in action on such a tuple list, you just need to supply one. For instance, `null [(1,2)]` uses it for a tuple-list. But in case of the empty list, there's no content of the list with which you would constrain the type. It may either be clear from the context, as in

```
Prelude> [null l | l <- [ [], [(1,2)], [(1,3)] ]]
[True,False,False]
```

or you may explicitly specify it with a signature

```
Prelude> null ([] :: [(String, Double)])
True
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to define an empty list with type `[(a,b)]`?

Simply **`[]`**. Indeed `[]` is an empty list, but the type of elements is free. It has type `[a]`, but `a` can be the same as `(b, c)` so a 2-tuple with two different types.

> For example I know that `null [1] == []` will give us `True`

[**`null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) is a function that takes an `f a` (in this case an `[a]`), and *returns a `Bool`*. It *checks* if a list is empty. It does *not* generate a list.

Answer (score 2):

i would declare my list like below :

```
let myList = [] :: [(Integer, Integer)]
```

then `myList` will have the type `:t myList` will yield `myList :: [(Integer, Integer)]`

When evaluating `null myList` it yields `True`

Answer (score 0):

Every type of list is represented as `[]`.  If you want to specify the type you can use a signature (`[] :: [(a, b)]`), but often the compiler can infer the type from context:

```
λ> [] == [(1, 'x')]
False
```